# GET http://localhost:3000/projects/assets/jquery.masonry.js 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I was trying to add a javascript-plugin masonry to my rails app and was wondering why it would only work for my welcome controller (localhost:3000/) but not for other controllers as localhost:3000/projects/1, although I'm using exactly the identical code.

I get this error:

> GET localhost:3000/projects/assets/jquery.masonry.js 404 (Not Found)

and

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'masonry'
>
> (anonymous function)
>
> e.resolveWith jquery.min.js
>
> e.extend.ready jquery.min.js
>
> c.addEventListener.z

I asume I get the error because of the wrong path localhost/projects/assets instead of localhost/assets, but I couldn't find out how to fix this.
Any help would be welcome!

This is the code in the view:

```
<% content_for(:scripts) do %>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
  $(function(){
    $('.squarescontainer').masonry({
      // options
      itemSelector : '.item',
      isAnimated: true
    });
  });
    
</script>
<% end %>
```

and this is my application.rb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ifub</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow&v1">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald">
  
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
    <script src = "assets/jquery.masonry.js"></script>
    <script src = "assets/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>

    <%= yield(:head) %>
    
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/logo' %>
    
    <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
      <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
  
    <div class="frame">
      <div class="container">
        <%= yield %>
        <%= yield :scripts %>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using URL relative to current path, so if your page is  `localhost:3000/project/page.html`, JS url will be `localhost:3000/project/assets/...`. Try to change your code like this:

```
<script src = "/assets/jquery.masonry.js"></script>
<script src = "/assets/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
```

see "/" added before assets. In that case browser will load script relatively to site root.
In that case even if your current page is `localhost:3000/project/page.html`, JS URL still will be `localhost:3000/assets/...`

Besides, you should connect only one version of plugin - minimized or not